# How to send messages to Azure Service Bus over Port 80?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

As per I know Azure Service bus uses port 9350, 9353 etc. to send messages. In my organization because of firewall policy we can't open these ports. So whenever I try to send messages to my queue in Azure I get error saying

> No DNS entries exist for host mycloudsevice.servicebus.windows.net".

Is there a way I can send these over port 80/443, as they are always open?

Let me know if any examples or code changes I can do.

Comment: the answer of Rob is totally right.  but the issues is indeed DNS related.  seems Microsoft has DNS issues today - might be related to that ?

Comment: When I send messages out side of my work network it works fine. Not sure if firewall is blocking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the Service Bus library to use HTTP by declaring the following:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

However it looks like you have a DNS problem not a TCP port problem, you might want to check that you have entered your service bus namespace correctly.

Comment: When I send messages out side of my work network it works fine. Not sure if firewall is blocking it. If I have to send it though http, where shall I use your code? Is it before creating namespace manager or before creating queue client? Also, how I can do it for https?

Comment: you have to set that static property before you open your service host (when hosting a service), or before you send your message to the service.

Comment: I tried that and worked when setting it up on http, though its deadly slow and not sure if reliable for large volume of messages.

Comment: It is definately slow, but as reliable as any other Http. Regardless of if you use Http or Tcp you should add some transient error handling if you are concerned about reliability.